# NGINX - Set root to sub directory

Tags: nginx, redirect

I use [Trellis](https://roots.io/trellis/) from the [Roots.io](https://roots.io/) WordPress framework stack. It sets up a LEMP environment for me.

The nginx root path is set to: `root /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web;`.

- I can't override this, any nginx-includes config changes I make are thrown inside the existing `server {}` I believe. - https://roots.io/docs/trellis/master/nginx-includes/

  - Inside the `/web` directory is a directory called `/static`.

Long story short. I want all traffic to be sent to the `/srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static` directory. So it acts like /static is the root and loads the website from there.

- I do not mean like this: https://www.example.co.uk/static
- Instead, https://www.example.co.uk/ should load from `/srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your nginx config file, in the server context, you can specify the directory which should become the web root.
If you use the **default config file**, /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, look for the '**root**' directive and adjust that to /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static
and set the **server_name** directive to your domain www.example.co.uk.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.co.uk;

etc.etc.
```

Don't forget to reload nginx so the changes can take effect. On Ubuntu:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Sorry I forgot to add that the `root` path is already set and I can't override it, Trellis handles it. I can however set `location {` configs etc.

Comment: When trying to override the root, I got this: `nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in` because the config files which are being used for the nginx includes are being thrown out, inside of the existing `server {`

Comment: Updated question with a nginx-includes link too.

Comment: could you add the nginx configs that are relevant to this setup in your question?